# deletion of 10K records from mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We are using below collection, where 2018 records in timeStamp  are present around 20k, can we delete these records through any scripts.

```
{
    "_id" : 999999001,
    "eventId" : "LAS081",
    "eventName" : "YouRefer",
    "timeStamp" : "2018-06-17T17:12:55.254Z",
    "eventMethod" : "Reporting",
    "resourceName" : "AddSTB",
    "targetType" : "",
    "resourseUrl" : "",
    "operationName" : "",
    "functionStatus" : "",
    "results" : "Tech UID: k201, Confirmation: X, BAN: 1442359, Initial Count =: 0
    "pageId" : "CloseJobView",
    "ban" : 144235039,
    "jobId" : 139980225,
    "wrid" : 139980225,
    "jobType" : "MRJ2IX",
    "Uid" : "K201",
    "techRegion" : "SE",
    "mgmtReportingFunction" : "N",
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below.

1. Find documents with limit - project id of the documents

   - use `gte` Jan 01 2018 00:00:00 and `lte` Dec 31 2018 23:59:59
2. Use DeleteOneModel with `bulk write`

Some referenece
[bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

If you face some issues with this, update this ques or post a new one. I suggest you to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

To delete documents with *year 2018*, use the following `deleteMany` query. The query uses Aggregation query date operators (`$toDate` and `$year`) with the help of the `$expr` operator.

*Sample input documents:*

```
{ "_id" : 0, "timeStamp" : "2020-11-01T23:00:28.123Z" }
{ "_id" : 1, "timeStamp" : "2018-06-17T17:12:55.254Z" }    // year is 2018
{ "_id" : 2, "timeStamp" : "2018-05-09T10:04:33.000Z" }    // year is 2018
{ "_id" : 9, "timeStamp" : "2019-05-09T01:35:09.099Z" }
```

*The delete operation:*

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { $expr: { $eq: [ { $year: { $toDate: "$timeStamp" } }, 2018 ] } } )
```

This will delete two documents with `_id`s, `1` and `2`.

Comment: OP mentioned that only 10k docs has to be deleted. That part is missing here I believe.